# Neo4j encryption

Tags: java, neo4j

How I can **encrypt** a Neo4j database?

For example if I have a small database only two nodes and one relationship, 
Node (Tom:person) and Node (ABC: company) and the relationship is Employer
and I have this query

Cypher query:

```
MATCH   (Tom:person) - [:EMPLOYER] - > (ABC:company)
WHERE   Tom.name = “Tom”
RETURN   company.name;
```

I have read about Neo4j encryption and I found the following:

Neo4j does not currently deal with data encryption explicitly, for scenarios where additional security is desired two approaches are common: 
Encrypting the filesystem the database sits upon and encrypting the data itself from the application.

Many Thanks

Comment: Which of those do you want to encrypt? Just the properties?

Answer (score 1):

As the explanation states, Neo4J has no built-in encryption. Either encrypt the filesystem or just the data before you insert it. The latter one is probably easier if you don't have the resources for a crypted filesystem, but it requires you to write more code.